# MySQL -- What language to use for DBA automation? (Perl, Python...?)

Tags: mysql

I've inherited an existing MySQL (5.x) instance and there's been little to no maintenance of the system

My question as a MSSQL DBA is -- What tools are most commonly used to automate administrative tasks when scripting/automation MySQL tasks?

For my MSSQL servers I mainly use native T-SQL, PowerShell or C# to create my automation processes.  T-SQL and Powershell are the most common as they are 'native' to the system and do not create dependencies by having to maintain additional software; C# brings  .NET version dependencies (sortof)....

I see that Python is quite popular as well as Perl, however my Perl knowledge is 'nil and Python looks fairly easy for what my requirements are.  Are there any good reasons to use one or another language for writing automation scripts/processes?

Comment: I'm not sure this question fits DBA.SE. Seems at the least best on SO. The answer is most likely going to be 'your choice'

Answer (score 3):

Before scripting anything against mysql, [**you should leverage the mysql client utilities**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/programs-admin-utils.html). That way, you do not find yourself reinventing the wheel.

As long as you have a good mastery over the mysql client utilities, whichever langauge you decide to program in for custom utilities is simply a matter of personal choice.

IMHO from a DBA perspective, it is best to perform basic shell scripting to call SQL scripts. Again, just a matter of personal choice.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, whatever you're familiar with. Our shop works in PHP, so our MySQL automation scripts are in PHP as well.